# gradient flow on $SU(n)$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, optimization, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Define the following cost functions $f_1, f_2 :SU(n) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f_1(U) = Re \left( \text{Tr}\left(G^{\dagger} U \right) \right)$ and $f_2(U) = \left| \left( \text{Tr}\left(G^{\dagger} U \right) \right) \right|^2$ for some fixed $G \in SU(n)$.

What are the gradients $\nabla f_1, \nabla f_2$ of these functions and how can they be expressed?

Comment: Where is $W$ used?

Comment: Fixed it, thanks

Comment: Your first sentence gets an endorsement from the Redundancy Department of Redundancy :-)

Comment: Is part of your question what the gradient of a function on $SU(n)$ is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So let's do $f_2$.  What you need to do is to first work out the
derivative in $M_n$, and then project onto $SU(n)$.  That is, we
identify $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ with its dual via the inner product $\langle U,V \rangle = \text{Re}\bigl(\text{Tr}(U^\dagger V)\bigr)$.  (You need to do this identification if you want to figure out gradient flow, because $U^{-1} \frac{dU}{dt}$ has to be in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.)  Note that I am thinking of $SU(n)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ as a Lie group or Lie algebra respectively over the *real numbers*, not the complex numbers.

So if $V \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$, then at $U \in SU(n)$ we have
$$ f_2(U(I + \epsilon V)) = f_2(U) + \epsilon \langle \nabla f_2,V
\rangle + O(\epsilon^2) .$$
Multiplying out, we obtain
$$ \langle \nabla f_2,V \rangle = 2 \text{Re} \bigl(\overline{\text{Tr}(G^\dagger U)} \, \text{Tr}(G^\dagger U V) \bigr) = 2 \text{Re} \bigl(\text{Tr}(H^\dagger U V) \bigr) ,$$
where
$$ K = \text{Tr}(G^\dagger U) \, G . $$
So we see that
$$ \nabla f_2 = 2 U^\dagger K + \Lambda ,$$
where $\Lambda \in \mathfrak{su}(n)^\perp$ is the "Lagrange multiplier"
such that $\nabla f_2 \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$.
Here
$$\mathfrak{su}(n)^\perp = \{\Lambda \in M_n : \text{$\langle \Lambda,W\rangle = 0$ for all $W \in
\mathfrak{su}(n)$}\} ,$$
After
some reflection, you realize that $\mathfrak{su}(n)^\perp$ is the space
of Hermitian matrices, and that $\nabla f_2$ is the anti-Hermitian part
of $2 U^\dagger K$, that is
$$ \nabla f_2 = U^\dagger K - K^\dagger U  .$$
So the gradient flow is
$$ \frac{dU}{dt} = U \, \nabla f_2 = K - U K^\dagger U .$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't parse this. $U+V$ is not in $SU(n)$ ever when $U,V \in SU(n)$. Did you mean to add a tangent vector $UA$ ($A \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$) to $U$?

Comment: I never said $V$ was in $SU(n)$.  Yes, it is meant to be in the Lie Algebra.

Comment: Ok, so you didn't. But you still need to say what $V$ is because not every choice is a tangent vector. This is in coordinates, is there a way without?

Comment: $\nabla f_2$ is going to be an element of the dual space of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.  One construction of the dual of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is to think of it as a quotient of $M_n$ via the duality $\langle \nabla f_2, V\rangle = \text{Tr}((\nabla f_2)^T V) = \sum_{ij} (\nabla f_2)_{ij} V_{ij} $.

Comment: Except actually I am looking at the dual of the lie algebra translated by left multiplication of $U$.  The whole thing is so much easier if you think of it in terms of matrices than abstract objects.

Comment: I agree about which set the gradient will reside within. However, I don't agree that working with matrices makes anything here clearer. If there is a coordinate free way, perhaps similar to recent results by Brocket on double bracket flows, then that would be great.

Comment: I don't know the work by Brocket.  Sorry.

Comment: It's great. Very worth a look.

Comment: Do you have a reference?  An online copy of the paper(s) would be fantastic.

Comment: There are quite a few. The key words are gradient and double bracket flow. They are mostly easily accessible with no pay wall etc..

Comment: This is very interesting to me, because I have been studying this paper: "Gradient descent of the frame potential," by Peter G. Casazza and Matthew Fickus, http://www.framerc.org/papers/Gradientdescentoftheframepotential.pdf (see also http://www.framerc.org/papers/RoadToEqualNormParsevalFrames.pdf) which use very similar gradient flows to solve problems in the communications industry.  I think the connection between the work of Brockett and these papers could be quite substantial.  In particular, they seem to have no reference to double bracket formulas.

Comment: OK, how about this rewrite?

Comment: Also, the gradient flow does depend upon the inner product you put on $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I was implicitly assuming using some multiple of the bi-invariant metric. Thanks for a nice answer there! That's exactly what I was after and what I meant when I asked for a coordinate free way!

Comment: After I check this a few more time, I will thank you in the paper I'm writing.

Comment: You might consider renaming $H$ as this question has a quantum context where $H$ could lead to misunderstanding!

Comment: I called it $K$.

Comment: Also, remember this is gradient flow uphill.  If you want to go downhill (as you would in optimization problems), put in a minus sign.